# Redux doesn't play well with Platform specific classes, ToolbarModal.ios.js version doesn't connect mapDispatchToProps

Tags: react-native, redux

I can't access the prop functions inside *.ios.js file, the android counterpart works well.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
updateTextInput, onResetPressed, getRecentSearches, getPopularNearYou,
filterWhereSelected,
})(ToolbarModal);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stupid mistake from my part, my action creator had a faulty, circular import:

```
import Suggestions from "../components/toolbarModal.ios";
```

corrected the import and everything works.. it would have been nice if Webstorm would have not proposed this import or it would have detected there is no Suggestions in toolbarModal.ios.